# What are some common reasons to fail a managed packaged security review?

Tags: managed-package, security-review

Just looking for the top few things to watch out for. Can anyone recommend common mistakes or areas of concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search on google:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_FAQ

> Q: What are common reasons why I would not pass the security review
>
> A: The following is a list of the top reasons why offerings are not
>      approved (Mirrors the OWASP Top 10):
>
> - Injection (SQL, XML etc.)
> - Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
> - Broken Authentication and Session Management
> - Insecure Direct Object References
> - Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF/XSRF)
> - Security Misconfiguration
> - Insecure Cryptographic Storage
> - Failure to Restrict URL Access
> - Insufficient Transport Layer Protection(no SSL          enforcement, weak or null ciphers, session cookies without secure       attribute
> - Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards

Comment: What I was going to say, but with more words. Thanks for keeping it simple.